# Binding multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tinymce

How can I bind multiple events on tinymce such that those events e.g. click, keyup and change have the same handler function?

I am trying like this but the events are not firing.

```
tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'click keyup change', function (ed, e) {
     // Handler here...                   
});
```

I also tried this where ed is my document

```
ed.bind('click keyup change', function (ed, e) {
     // Handler here...
});
```

but bind is not defined for tinymce. How can I get this working?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `tinymce` but you can create a function then pass it without `()` as callback.

Comment: `tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'click', thefunction);` `tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'keyup', thefunction);` `function thefunction(){ //whatever }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function myFunction(ed, e) {
    // do what you want
}

tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'click', myFunction);
tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'keyup', myFunction);
tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'change', myFunction);
```

Comment: Hehe I was off by 21 seconds. `+1`

Comment: Is this the same for Tinymce 5 as well?

Answer (score 2):

Make one callback function and pass it to each of them

I do **not** believe that `tinymce` gives you the ability to add multiple events at once.

For example:

```
callbackFn = function (ed, e) {
     // Handler here...                   
};
tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'click', callbackFn );
tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed, 'keyup', callbackFn );
...
```

Comment: It seems not but I posted just to be sure. Thanks for your answer :)